# Getting weird native crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash

I have an app which is developed only with Java and nothing with NDK, but I'm still getting some native crashes.

I'm getting these crashes in Android 4.4 only. The problem is I don't have any clue how to debug these kind of stacktraces.

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 0000000000011884  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1191)
  native: pc 000000000000dd23  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
  native: pc 000000000008249d  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+24)
  native: pc 000000000002ae2d  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+244)
  native: pc 0000000000016da9  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+924)
  native: pc 000000000001995b  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+642)
  native: pc 00000000000252fd  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+72)
  native: pc 000000000000c6a9  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
  native: pc 0000000000020d0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  native: pc 00000000000519af  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  native: pc 000000000002a1a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 0000000000031650  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  native: pc 000000000002ece8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  native: pc 0000000000063e15  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  native: pc 0000000000063e39  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
  native: pc 0000000000058b0b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 000000000000d288  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  native: pc 000000000000d420  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
```

Anyone can point me to the right direction regarding this?

Comment: Need more code and explanation.

Comment: This is the only stacktrace I got from Developer Console

Comment: @AndroidGuy You got the solution? I have the same issue with same version 4.4. Still couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @Sakthi unfortunately still not

Comment: @AndroidGuy Ok, Thanks for ur reply

Comment: @AndroidGuy any solution after two years ? :))